# Using IF Then and Response.Redirect in ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So I have three pages.
The first page I define a link with a string

```
<a href="divProgLog.asp?div=Division 2">
```

The second page I grab the string and assign a variable

```
<%  divrec = request.QueryString("div")%>
```

The third page processes everything. I would like for the process to be if the string is equaled to Division 2 the user will be redirected to another page. I'm using the following code but its not working

```
divstring = "divisions.asp?div=" & divrec & "&Last_Name=" & Last_Name & "&First_Name="    &First_Name
divstring2 = "divisions2.asp?div=" & divrec & "&Last_Name=" & Last_Name & "&First_Name=" &First_Name
if divrec = Division 2 then
Response.Redirect divstring2
else
Response.Redirect divstring
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use VB.Net for a long time, but try this:

```
divstring = "divisions.asp?div=" & divrec & "&Last_Name=" & Last_Name & "&First_Name="    &First_Name
divstring2 = "divisions2.asp?div=" & divrec & "&Last_Name=" & Last_Name & "&First_Name=" &First_Name
If divrec = "Division 2" Then
Response.Redirect(divstring2)
Else
Response.Redirect(divstring)
End If
```

Your page shouldn't be compilable by the way.

Do not forget to use an upper case for `If`, `Then` and `End If`.

Also `Division 2` is a string so you have to surround it with double-quotes.

`Response.Redirect` is a method so parameters are specified between parenthesis.

Comment: By the way is it a VB.Net source code?? Try to compile your page and please post the error message if your problem is not fixed.

Comment: That's classic ASP and this means VBScript

Comment: Your awesome!! Thanks for your help. Its VB Script

Comment: In VBScript case doesn't matter, and you can call methods without parenthesis. The only error was missing double quotes around the string value. However, it's still good advice to keep the Case and use parenthesis, will make the transition to  C# easier. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try taking the space out of Division 2 ID and rename it to Division2.

i.e. `<a href="divProgLog.asp?div=Division2">`

Then modify your code to be

```
If divrec = "Division2" Then
    Response.Redirect(divstring2)
Else
    Response.Redirect(divstring)
End if
```

Comment: Space is totally fine, no need to remove it. Only the quotes were missing.